# Can I host a CSS stylesheet on Pastebin?

Tags: html, css, pastebin

This is more out of curiosity than anything, but is it possible to save a stylesheet on Pastebin and load it in an HTML document? I tried to do it the way you'd normally link a stylesheet, but it didn't work. Here's the test code I used:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="http://pastebin.com/0dY5eBga" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>This is a test. Will it work? Probably not.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code I'm trying to use is saved at http://pastebin.com/0dY5eBga.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot import stylesheets from pastebin in this way, even using the raw url, because the pastebin server sets a `Content-Type` header of `text/plain` on the HTTP response. This will prevent the file from being properly interpreted as a CSS stylesheet.

For instance, Chrome will give the following error:

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain`

And then it will refuse to apply your styles.

Please see the following MDN articles for details about incorrect MIME types on CSS files - many browsers block resources with incorrect MIME types:
[Incorrect MIME Type for CSS Files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files)
[Configuring Server MIME Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types)

---

Here is a live example of CSS ***not*** working when linked from Pastebin, because the server does not send it with the `text/css` MIME type:

```html
<link href="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0dY5eBga" rel="stylesheet"/>

<p>This text is not red.</p>
```

Comment: Is there a proxy like https://raw.githack.com but for pastebin?